# Get Opencart Order ID in COD Payment Module Redirect Link

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

First of all thank you for giving your valuable time to help me.

My Situation -

> I am using Opencart 2.1.0.1
>
> Cash on Delivery Payment Method
>
> Custom OnePageCheckout
>
> Custom Theme

I have implemented a custom process which verifies the customer from our own database via a cron job running every minute.

> *This is the default code in Opencart* 
>   **catalog/view/theme/template/payment/cod.tpl**

```
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_confirm; ?>" id="button-confirm" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" />
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#button-confirm').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'index.php?route=payment/cod/confirm',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-confirm').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-confirm').button('reset');
        },
        success: function() {
            location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
        }
    });
});
//--></script>
```

As I want to redirect the customer to the following page after successful checkout.
https://www.myopencartstore.com/**confirm.php?order_id=$order_id**

Required Action  : I want to pass on the **order_id** variable in the url parameter as highlighted in bold above.

**My Modified Code -**

```
<div class="buttons">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_confirm; ?>" id="button-confirm" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" />
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#button-confirm').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'index.php?route=payment/cod/confirm',
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#button-confirm').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-confirm').button('reset');
        },
        success: function() {
            location = '<?php echo 'confirm-success.php'; ?>';
        }
    });
});
//--></script>
```

Please help how to do the same.

I want to bye-pass the ***checkout/success*** page.

> I've tried implementing **$this->session->data['order_id'];** to get the Order ID parameter.

I've tried all my efforts and thus maximum I could do is to *just* redirect to the desired page but without any parameters.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please show your steps

Answer (score 1):

If your page url is confirm.php the follow the following things.

Open catalog\view\theme\default\template\payment\cod.tpl

change

```
location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';
```

to

```
location = '<?php echo HTTP_SERVER; ?>confirm.php';
```

Or you can change on page catalog/controller/payment/cod.php

```
$data['continue'] = $this->url->link('checkout/success');
```

to

```
$data['continue'] = HTTP_SERVER.'confirm.php?order_id='.$this->session->data['order_id'];
```

Thanks

**Edited**

So you can write in this way.
In catalog\controller\checkout\success.php

after

```
if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {
```

Write

```
$data['order_id'] = $this->session->data['order_id'];
```

For redirect from common/success page to confirm.php page after 5 sec you have to write following things before

```
<script><!-- 
$(document).ready(function () { 
      window.setTimeout(function(){ 
     window.location.href ='<?php echo HTTP_SERVER; ?>confirm.php?order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>'; }, 5000);
 });
 --></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think so you read my post clearly. Please check the link I require. Your method will generate something link store.com/index.php?route=xxxxx.  Whereas I want confirm.php, in place of index.php

Comment: Okay so I think you have a direct page in root named as confirm.php.

Comment: So please change the following in catalog\view\theme\default\template\payment\cod.tpl page

location = '<?php echo $continue; ?>';

to

location = '<?php echo HTTP_SERVER; ?>confirm.php';

Comment: I want to add up a feature, as I have tracking module installed on the checkout/success page, I'm unable to pull those details on confirm.php (root directory) Hence, I think redirecting in 5 seconds from checkout/success to confirm.php would be a better option, so as to not byepass the default procedure and finish the customized job also. How to do that ?

Comment: I want the Order Total value on the 'confirm.php' page.

As this will be used in a javascript Tracking Code - "value" parameter
For Ex.

<script>
  fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
    value: 0,
    currency: 'INR',
    content_type: 'Product',
  });
</script>


How to do this ?

Comment: Please send me the tracking module zip file so that I can check it and let you know. You can send it to my mail id: prasant200582@gmail.com

Comment: For redirect from common/success page to confirm.php page after 5 sec
you have to write following things before <?php echo $footer; ?> in catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\success.tpl file

<script><!--
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function(){

        window.location.href ='<?php echo HTTP_SERVER; ?>confirm.php';

    }, 5000);
});
--></script>

Comment: <?php echo HTTP_SERVER; ?>confirm.php?$order_id

This is the required above link. I need Order ID also.

Comment: So you can write in this way.
In catalog\controller\checkout\success.php

after 

if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {

Write
 $data['order_id'] = $this->session->data['order_id'];

And you have to write following things before <?php echo $footer; ?> in catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\success.tpl file 

<script><!-- 
$(document).ready(function () { 
      window.setTimeout(function(){ 
     window.location.href ='<?php echo HTTP_SERVER; ?>confirm.php?order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>'; }, 5000);
 });
 --></script>

Comment: Not working, the redirection does not work. I'm using a custom checkout, instead of "checkout/checkout", my link for checkout is "onepagecheckout/checkout" and checkout success is same as default. "Checkout/Success".

Comment: You have written you want to redirect from checkout/success page..
I want to bye-pass the checkout/success page.
Now you are saying different things. 
Okay no Issues You can write this code to the current success page.

Comment: Please read again, I first said I want to bye-pass it, but I have tracking modules installed on the success page. Hence I need to redirect FROM the checkout/success page.

Your code isn't working!

Comment: In catalog\controller\checkout\success.php

My code updated code is - 
<?php
class ControllerCheckoutSuccess extends Controller {
 public function index() {
  $this->load->language('checkout/success');

  if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {
       $data['order_id'] = $this->session->data['order_id'];
      $this->load->model('checkout/order');
 $data['orderDetails'] = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);

 // $order_id = $orderDetails['order_id'];
   $this->cart->clear();

--------------------REMAINING CODE--------------------

Comment: In 
catalog/view/theme/fastor/template/common/success.tpl 
and
catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/success.tpl

Updated Code - 
<?php echo $header; 
$theme_options = $this->registry->get('theme_options');
$config = $this->registry->get('config'); 
include('catalog/view/theme/' . $config->get('config_template') . '/template/new_elements/wrapper_top.tpl'); ?>

<script><!-- $(document).ready(function () { window.setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href ='<?php echo HTTP_SERVER; ?>confirm.php?order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>'; }, 5000); }); --></script>

Comment: Hi, Please send me the following files
catalog\controller\checkout\success.php and
catalog/view/theme/fastor/template/common/success.tpl
I will correct it

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you

Kindly Replace in this file as
catalog/controller/extension/payment/cod.php

```
$data['continue'] = $this->url->link('checkout/success');
```

to

```
$data['continue'] = HTTP_SERVER.'confirm.php?order_id='.$this->session->data['order_id'];
```

Comment: I want to add up a feature, as I have tracking module installed on the checkout/success page, I'm unable to pull those details on confirm.php (root directory)

Hence, I think redirecting in 5 seconds from checkout/success to confirm.php would be a better option, so as to not byepass the default procedure and finish the customized job also.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

And what if I write a script like this:

```
for ($order_id = 0; $order_id < 1000000; $order_id++)
{
// Pseudo-code to save the data at this URL:
https://www.myopencartstore.com/confirm.php?order_id=$order_id
}
```

I now have all your customer info!

So I suggest you do not do this.

Comment: @couldn't get you! Could you elaborate?

Comment: order no ( 0 to 999999) operation will be accounrding your code as on 
https://www.myopencartstore.com/confirm.php